# Is it possible to have SQL server look for entities under other schemas than DBO when the schema name isn't specified in the query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, schema, naming-convention

Not sure if this is a thing, and I understand it's better practice to write your queries using the two-part naming convention, but it would be cool if SQL Server had a way to setup a schema priority list.

That way when you execute a query that references entities without their correlating schemas, the server is smart enough to search for those entities in each schema on the priority list, in order, until it finds the entity.

I would find this mostly helpful in a lot of ad-hoc queries I write that won't ever be formalized.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42955/query-without-having-to-specify-tables-schema

Comment: Short answer - no. The database engine will look in the current user's default schema followed by the dbo schema. It is not configurable.